# Finding Inverse of Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This inverse function isn't making sense to me:
$P = \frac{m}{13 + m}$ 
I would like to inverse this so I can use $P$ to get $m$. 
I used a calculator online and got $\frac{13p}{1 - p} = m$, but I am completely clueless on how to get this answer. Was wondering if anyone can help me understand this?

Comment: Please use tags relevant to the question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't understand how to get the answer. I'm too ret​ar​ded.

Comment: This is the first step to perform in these types of problems. https://youtu.be/JPdwgJ4T-fs?si=Y6Zd66ZvGa8Wwhez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how. 
$$P = \frac{m}{13 + m}$$
Multiply by the denominator $\implies P(13 + m) = m$ 
Foil $\implies 13P + mP = m$
Subtract $m$ to move to front $\implies m - 13P - Pm = 0$ 
Add $13P$ to both sides $\implies m - Pm = 13P$ 
Make it foil: $\implies m(1 - P) = 13P$ 
Last step, divide on both sides. And your answer: 
$m = \frac{13P}{1 - P}$

Answer (score 0):

Set $p = \frac{m}{13 + m}$ and solve for $m$.

$m(1-p) = 13 p$.... and thus....

$m = \frac{13 p}{1-p}$.

If this isn't clear enough, I don't think I can help.

By the way, this isn't a "complex function" (i.e., on that uses $i = \sqrt{-1}$) and it isn't even a *complicated* function.

Can you give any function that is simpler than what you've posed?

Comment: I'm too ret​ar​ded to understand :-(